# How can I store resources in a cookie for faster load time

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, setcookie

I know how to set a cookie whether it be in javascript or php, but from all the examples on the internet I only see something similar to this:

`setcookie("name", "Chris", time()*3600, "/")`

But there is no documentation or tutorial on how to apply this to a real appliaction and store real data in the cookie (and not just a name like "Chris" for tutorial purposes).

I would like the clients browser to remember session IDs and static resources like images, stylesheets, javascript,... (for faster load time)

Should I just send a json object with the url location of the resources and the session ids as key/value pairs or how is that done?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Cookies is the wrong approach for remembering static resources.  Network request caching should take care of those.

Comment: Although you could store data in a cookie, if it's more than simple SessionID's etc, you might want to look into localeStorage, or even IndexedDB https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API,  For static assets like images / sound etc, let the browser cache do it's work.

Answer (score 0):

The static resources can be cached intrinsically by the browser by using the [Cache Control Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

You don't need cookies to do it. Just make sure you set appropriate Cache Control Headers on your web server, for any static resource you desire.

Also, if you try to store static content (like images etc) in the cookies, you need to write your own code to get it back from the cookies and render into the DOM (which is highly costly).